# how to scale / increase font size for iphone 4 , 5 and 6 using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, iphone-6

I am trying to use different font size for iphone  5 , 6 and ipad using autolayout. I tried this setting like below screen shot but the fonts size is not giving the required results :
[image]

Comment: u can't,U have to think in size classes not according to diff phone

Comment: wat should i do now?

Comment: check it programmatically

Comment: Auto layout doesn't have anything to do with setting font to your label. You need to do it via code

Answer (score 1):

you can differentiate fonts in iphone and ipad see this [link](http://prntscr.com/7pdhqr)